# Firebase firestore on Flutter Web NoSuchMethodError. 'docs'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run my flutter chat app on web but I encountered this error

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
>
> 'docs'
> method not found
> Receiver: null
> Arguments: []
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> StreamBuilder

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT9X6.png)

It is working on my android emulator so maybe there's missing on my web configuration so what I've tried is adding the firebase on my index.html and following https://stackoverflow.com/a/67518124/15916393 advice but still the error occurs.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

here is my code

```
class Messages extends StatelessWidget {
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('chat')
      .orderBy(
        'createdAt',
        descending: true,
      )
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
    if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
    final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs ?? 'default data';
    return ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
      itemCount: chatDocs.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
        chatDocs[index].data()['text'],
        chatDocs[index].data()['username'],
        chatDocs[index].data()['userImage'],
        chatDocs[index].data()['userId'] == user.uid,
        key: ValueKey(chatDocs[index].id),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the case where there is an error in loading the data

```
builder: (ctx, chatSnapshot) {
  if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
  //  Check if there was an error
  if (snapshot.hasError) {
    return Text('Error loading data: ${snapshot.error!}');
  }
  final chatDocs = chatSnapshot.data.docs ?? 'default data';
  ...
```

I highly recommend following the patterns outline in the samples in the FlutterFire documentation like the above from [reading realtime changes](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes).

Comment: flutterfire documentation really helps me. thanks for providing it!